# Server side serial over python tornado chat

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, serial-port, tornado

I am looking for a way to modify the Tornado Websockets Chat Demo in order to communicate with a serial port on the server over the chat. Shown below is the method(?) called on when a message is sent. I can write to serial fine sending the body of the message to the serial.write(). But the problem is I am only able to get the serial feedback once. However in my current application the serial may send in data more than just when spoken to.

```
    ...
    import serial
    serial = serial.Serial("COM3", 57600)
    ...
    def on_message(self, message):
        test = ""
        logging.info("got message %r", message)
        parsed = tornado.escape.json_decode(message)

        serial.write(parsed["body"] + "\n")
        logging.info("SENT " + parsed["body"] + "\n")
        test = serial.readline()

        chat = {
            "id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
            "body": test,
            }

        chat["html"] = self.render_string("message.html", message=chat)

        ChatSocketHandler.update_cache(chat)
        ChatSocketHandler.send_updates(chat)
```

Is there a way to constantly poll the serial and handle the websockets IO at the same time? Also if there is an easier alternative to Tornado with realtime multiple page updates I would not be opposed. Although I do like Tornado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are open for other approaches, you might be interested in this [complete working example](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/wamp/serial2ws), demonstrating **real-time charts in browser** instances driven **from an Arduino sensor board via serial and WebSocket**. This uses Autobahn and Twisted.

Disclosure: I'm original author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Comment: Funny enough a few hours after I posted this I found Autobahn and have had much luck. I too would recommend it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a different approach using Tornado and Python's multiprocessing library.  Details are available here:

[Raspberry Pi + Tornado + Arduino](http://niltoid.com/blog/raspberry-pi-arduino-tornado/)